# Java stream parallel behaviour for allMatch, noneMatch, filter and map

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, behavior

I read in another post that after investigation it was found that the anyMatch terminal operation works in such a way that each thread (operating on a substream) periodically checks if other threads have found a result and if so, all other threads are stopped.

I assume, but wondered if someone could verify if `noneMatch` and `allMatch` also operate in this way, so if when running `noneMatch`, one thread finds an actual match, then the operation can return false. So do all other threads periodically check for this in the same manner described for `anyMatch`? Similary, does the inverse apply for `allMatch`?

Furthermore, I wondered if there was any difference when running the `filter` and `map` operations in parallel as to whether they are run on an ordered or unordered stream. On an ordered stream, I assume the most logical benefit is simply that the different threads can process each substream created and then merge them all back together in the same order. For an unordered stream, does this hold any advantages for such operations as I'm struggling to think of any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All three `anyMatch`, `allMatch` and `noneMatch` are implemented using the same [`MatchOps`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/MatchOps.java?av=f) class with different flags set. So they work in pretty similar manner. All of them are short-circuiting and not ordered, so it does not matter whether your stream source is ordered or not: these operations will perform equally fast.

The operations like `map` and `filter` do not have any benefit with unordered source. Unordered source changes the algorithm for `distinct`, `limit`, `skip`, `takeWhile` (Java-9), `dropWhile` (Java-9). Seems that normal reduction (via `reduce` or `collect`) does not optimize the unordered case (though my very preliminary research suggests that such optimization would be possible).

Comment: That is a fantastic reply - thank you very much! So to clarify, allMatch and noneMatch when ran in parallel will have threads for each substream check if other threads have been able to define an early result?

Comment: Furthermore, how do I find the actual source code for methods such as findFirst, through grep? Which particular class is the actual implementation of this method in?

Comment: @user3780370, yes, other threads check for early result in `allMatch`/`noneMatch`. Grep may help, but usually I use IDE features to navigate into JDK code. Both Eclipse and IDEA can do this in a pretty comfortable way.

Comment: I'm looking now through Eclipse - where did you locate the fact that findFind() becomes findAny() if the source is unordered? Where is the specific source code that dictates that, i.e. specific class and method? thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3780370, oops, I was wrong! `findFirst` is not optimized for unordered source. [Posted a patch](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-January/038159.html), hopefully it will be accepted.

Comment: I assume findAny() behaves as per anyMatch, allMatch and noneMatch though, in that threads check other threads for an early result? Are you able to pinpoint to me as to where in the source code of the API that this logic occurs, in addition to something like allMatch and how it could end early if it finds a negative match?

Comment: @Tranquility, parallel evaluation of `findFirst/findAny` is performed by [`FindTask`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/FindOps.java#FindOps.FindTask) which extends [`AbstractShortCircuitTask`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/AbstractShortCircuitTask.java#43) like `MatchTask` used for `anyMatch`. AbstractShortCircuitTask holds shared result which is common between all the subtasks.